# How can I bind the position of a line to the transforming position of an Ellipse in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've got an ellipse that is being translated about by a transform, as specified by the following template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="VectorTemplate">
    <Ellipse>
        <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform X="{Binding Path=X, Converter={StaticResource SomeValueConverter}}" Y="{Binding Path=Y, Converter={StaticResource SomeValueConverter}}" />
        </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
    </Ellipse>
</DataTemplate>
```

Elsewhere, I'm defining the ContentControl this renders:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="SkeletonTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource VectorTemplate}" />
            </Style> 
        </Grid.Resources>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Head}" x:Name="HeadCtrl"/>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding ShoulderCenter}" x:Name="ShoulderCenterCtrl"/>
        <Line X1="{Binding Path=????, ElementName=HeadCtrl}" Y1="{Binding Path=????, ElementName=HeadCtrl}" X2="{Binding Path=????, ElementName=ShoulderCenterCtrl}" Y2="{Binding Path=????, ElementName=ShoulderCenterCtrl}" />
    </Grid>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

As you'll see from the portion that is question marks, I'm not sure how to retrieve the X or Y position from the ContentControl.

This is somewhat simplified from what the code actually contains, so I do have a reason for wanting to bind to the translated position and not just binding to the X value itself (I wind up using a ValueConverter on it).  I could just add the same ValueConverter to each and every X and Y coordinate and just specify the field back on the viewmodel, but that seems clunky.

I *should* be able to bind to the position of these moving elements - can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, you want your line to link the head to the shoulders.

If so, I would directly bind the line positions to the model being the datacontext of the hierarchichalDataTemplate:

```
<Line X1="{Binding Path=Head.X}" Y1="{Binding Path=Head.Y}" X2="{Binding Path=ShoulderCenter.X}" Y2="{Binding Path=ShoulderCenter.Y}" />
```

Hope this help.

Antoine

Comment: As you'll see in the second to last paragraph of my post, I *don't* want to bind to the model itself.  I'm applying a ValueConverter to those values to position the Vectors, and I don't want to have to reapply the converter over and over again if there's a way to bind to the ellipses themselves.

Perhaps I should have written those into the implementation I pasted, but I figured it would be sufficient to mention it in the body of the post.  I went ahead and edited to make it extra clear.